# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Wondering if anyone can help me with this since I'm a javascript noob.

My code works fine except for an error that I get:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: marker

The moveMarker function is not seeing the variable "marker".  I realize that I've added it within a keypress function and that's the only way I can get it to work but I don't know how to place the variable so that it can be accessed globally.  I've added it outside the functions but then the map doesn't load at all.

Can anyone give me a hand here?

Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
var nature = new google.maps.LatLng(45.51948, -73.59488);
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.51948, -73.59488);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 13,
center: latlng
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'http://pa-nature.supermarchepa.com/assets/pa-nature.kmz'
});
ctaLayer.setMap(map);

var natureMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: nature,
  map: map,
  icon: 'http://pa-nature.supermarchepa.com/assets/pa-solo-map.svg',
  title: 'PA Nature'
});

var input = document.getElementById('address');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
    types: ["geocode"]
});

autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(14);
    }

    moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
});

$("input").focusin(function () {
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            infowindow.close();
            var firstResult = $(".pac-container .pac-item:first").text();

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({"address":firstResult }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location});
                    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                        placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                    moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                    $("input").val(firstResult);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

 function moveMarker(placeName, latlng){
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
    infowindow.setContent(placeName);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
 }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: TL;DR, but pretty sure the issue is that the `geocode` and other functions are **asynchronous**, and you can't make `marker` *"global"* when it's not even there yet.-

Comment: I think you want to add `marker` as an argument to `moveMarker`, and pass in your call to `moveMarker` in the keypress callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your marker variable global (like the map and geocoder variables).  Hide the marker if it already exists before overwriting it.

Working code snippet:

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
var nature = new google.maps.LatLng(45.51948, -73.59488);

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.51948, -73.59488);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://pa-nature.supermarchepa.com/assets/pa-nature.kmz'
    });
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);

    var natureMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: nature,
        map: map,
        icon: 'http://pa-nature.supermarchepa.com/assets/pa-solo-map.svg',
        title: 'PA Nature'
    });

    var input = document.getElementById('address');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
        types: ["geocode"]
    });

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        infowindow.close();
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(14);
        }

        moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
    });

    $("input").focusin(function () {
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                infowindow.close();
                var firstResult = $(".pac-container .pac-item:first").text();

                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({
                    "address": firstResult
                }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if ( !! marker && marker.setMap) marker.setMap(null);
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                            placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                        moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                        $("input").val(firstResult);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
        if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) return;  // or create a marker
        marker.setPosition(latlng);
        infowindow.setContent(placeName);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="address" />
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: this works nicely except I'm getting the following error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'marker.setPosition')"  also, when I run it locally, the markers don't show, but on the server, the markers work as expected.  thanks

Comment: Does the code snippet have the same error?  If not, is your code the same as the code snippet? (did you remove the `var` from in front of the marker code inside the geocoder callback)

Comment: yes, I just checked, the code snippet does have the same error.

Comment: What are you doing to cause it?  I don't see that error in Chrome when inputting an address and changing it once (Montreal first, then New York). [fiddle which also doesn't exhibit the error you report](http://jsfiddle.net/zenbqz0z/)

Comment: Nothing. Running your code on this page and seeing the error in the console. Safari on a Mac. Here's a link to my live site: http://pa-nature.supermarchepa.com/delivery-zone.html

Comment: This is a timing issue. The placeMarker function is being called on the 'place_changed' event the first time before the marker is created.  Fixed my answer.

Comment: this fixed the issue but now unfortunately, on mouse click, the marker doesn't show up.  on keypress enter, it works flawlessly.  Tried it on chrome too.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the variable scope.

```
    $("input").focusin(function () {
    ...
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location});
    ...
    });
```

This is considered a jquery function. `moveMarker` is a different function. You can not simply call `marker.setPosition(latlng);` since it is declared within the previous function and it is not known globally. You need to pass the marker as a parameter in the moveMarker function.